# JOIN multiple MySQL tables in query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not sure if this is even possible, or if my JOIN-fu just isn't strong enough(it's pretty wimpy to tell you the truth). I have 3 tables which are tied together with a UID. I'm trying to get information from a result from all of them into one query, except I'm having trouble with making sure the result is what I want.

users

> ```
> ========= USERS ==========
> | uid      | nickname    |
> --------------------------
> | testusr1 | Test User 1 |
> | testusr2 | Test User 2 |
> | testusr3 | Test User 3 |
> | testusr4 | Test User 4 |
>
> ============= GALLERY ===========
> | id | uid      | ext | profile |
> ---------------------------------
> | 1  | testusr1 | png | 1       |
> | 2  | testusr2 | jpg | 1       |
> | 3  | testusr3 | png | 1       |
> | 4  | testusr4 | png | 1       |
> | 5  | testusr4 | jpg | 0       |
>
> ============= FRIENDS =============
> | sender   | reciever    | status |
> -----------------------------------
> | testusr1 | testusr3    | 0      |
> | testusr2 | testusr3    | 1      |
> | testusr2 | testusr1    | 1      |
> | testusr3 | testusr4    | 1      |
> ```

What I'm trying to do is get all of a user's friends. Friends are in the friends table where the status = 1. The uid can be either the sender or the reciever. In the table above, testusr3's friends are: testusr2 and testusr4

From here I want to snag the nickname from users, and the id from gallery WHERE profile = 1 AND uid = (that friend's ID).

So far, my query looks like:

```
$query = "SELECT u.uid AS USERID, g.id, g.ext, f.sender, f.reciever 
FROM friends f
LEFT JOIN gallery g ON g.uid = f.sender AND g.profile = 1 
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.uid = f.sender 
WHERE f.status = 1 
AND (f.sender = '$sentuid' OR f.reciever = '$sentuid')";
```

But, it labels all of the results as f.sender...and I'm pretty sure the g.profile = 1 isn't working. It does grab the friends accurately though. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: don't do a left join, use inner join

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or) a sqlfiddle together with the desired result.

Comment: And presumably sender and receiver are like initiator and reciprocator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Untested Solution

Best place to start is to get the matching records in a single column, with `UNION`. Then you have all the UIDs you need, in one place.

```
SELECT f.uid, u.nickname, g.id
FROM
(
    (SELECT reciever as uid FROM friends where status=1 and sender='$sentuid')
    UNION 
    (SELECT sender as uid FROM friends where status=1 and reciever='$sentuid')
) f
LEFT JOIN gallery g ON f.uid = g.uid and profile=1
LEFT Join users u ON f.uid = u.uid
```

#### Side notes:

- Generally a bad idea to use char for an ID field.
- For performance reasons, you may be better off actually using **more** storage space, and doubling up on the 'friends' records. i.e.: two entries for each friendship.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you're really close, but a SQLfiddle would help. I believe you are right, `g.profile = 1` is not working because you have no table reference for it, might as well take it out. But because of the join, you should be able to select it.

```
$query = "SELECT u.uid AS USERID, g.id, g.ext, g.profile, f.sender, f.reciever 
FROM friends f
LEFT JOIN gallery g ON g.uid = f.sender
RIGHT JOIN users u ON u.uid = f.sender 
WHERE f.status = 1 
AND (f.sender = '$sentuid' OR f.reciever = '$sentuid')";
```